# how to use 1 for loop to add two list to dictionary in python? expected result {'a':[1,2]}

Tags: python

I have written the code which works perfectly but I am trying to use only one for loop but it didn't work out

Here is the python code

```
lst_one=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
lst_two=['a','b','c','a','b','c','a','a']

result={}

for createname in range(len(lst_one)):
    result[lst_two[createname]]=[]

for value in range(len(lst_one)):
    result[lst_two[value]].append(lst_one[value])

print(result)
```

above code result {'a': [1, 4, 7, 8], 'b': [2, 5], 'c': [3, 6]}

it is working fine using two loop

is it possible to use one loop instead of two-loop
I am using range loop, not lambda, zip and .....

Comment: Did any answer provide what you were looking for? if yes please consider accepting it :)

Comment: Is this code just for the sake of example, or are you actually trying to find the indices of the letters?

Answer (score 3):

you can use `defaultdict`  which create a dictionary  where type of value you define like list or int or dict and it will handle if the key is there or not . if present then do operation on value and if not then make a key and value air

```
lst_one=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
lst_two=['a','b','c','a','b','c','a','a']

from collections import defaultdict

result = defaultdict(list)

for a,b in zip(lst_one, lst_two):
    result[b].append(a)

print(dict(result))
```

output

```
{'a': [1, 4, 7, 8], 'b': [2, 5], 'c': [3, 6]}
```

if you not wana use default dict then, you can use below code which doing the same way like default dict

```
lst_one=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
lst_two=['a','b','c','a','b','c','a','a']


result ={}
for a, b in zip(lst_one, lst_two):
    if b not in result.keys():
        result.update({b:[a]})
    else:
        result[b].append(a)
print(result)
```

output

```
{'a': [1, 4, 7, 8], 'b': [2, 5], 'c': [3, 6]}
```

Comment: your approach is much better for learning what is going on, mine is only good if you don't want to waste lines :P

Comment: @jojo being from c programming background, i prefer to write to from the beginning, also i didn't had master roshi with me to guide me at beginning, all i had to go vegeta way :P

Comment: even with master roshi at your side it takes practice until you can destroy the moon with a single kamehameha :)

Comment: yes, and taken even more practice to get the ultra instinct

Answer (score 3):

Use [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) + [setdefault](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault):

```
lst_one = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
lst_two = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'a']

result = {}

for o, t in zip(lst_one, lst_two):
    result.setdefault(t, []).append(o)

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
{'a': [1, 4, 7, 8], 'b': [2, 5], 'c': [3, 6]}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using [`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) from the [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#module-itertools) package if you want to condense this:

```py
from itertools import groupby

{a[0]:[e[1] for e in b] for a,b in groupby(sorted(zip(lst_two, lst_one)), lambda x:x[0])}
```